# AbsoluteTiming of nested integration gives strange result

Tags: numerical-integration, function-construction

I found somewhat strange behaviour of nested integration timings. Consider the following code:

```
a1 := NIntegrate[x , {x, 0, 1}];
a2[x_] := NIntegrate[x, {x, 0, 1}];

NIntegrate[a1, {x, 0, 1}] // AbsoluteTiming
NIntegrate[a2[x], {x, 0, 1}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

The output is usually like this:

> {0.0171206, 0.5}
>
> {0.0103186, 0.5}

Normally the evaluation time of `a2` is 1.5-2 times faster. The only difference is the definition of the inner integration function - with or without argument. The definition of `a2` makes no sense for me, but its real execution speed always higher.. Considering numerous similar calculations with much more complicated functions one can save almost half of the time with this trick. Can someone please explain how it works and whether it will always produce correct results?

UDP:
I made the code as simple as I could.

Comment: `a1` and `a2` are not dependent on `t`, and `a2`'s `x` is a dummy variable. What gives?

Comment: @J.M. yea, I accidentally left it. Now I've edited the code again. Thanks.

Comment: Still not sure how `a2` is supposed to work; surely `NIntegrate[5 fun[5], {5, -4, 4}, args]` for `a2[5]` does not at all make sense.

Comment: @J.M. Right, this definition makes no sense for me also. But surprisingly it works inside `NIntegrate` and with beneficial speed..

Answer (score 3):

The trace shows what happens, but not why, which reasons remain obscure to me.
`NIntegrate` internally evaluates the integrand, so ultimately the outside integral is computed on the integrand `0.5`, which is the value of both `a1` and `a2[x]`.
The slower way has essentially three evaluations of `NIntegrate`.
The faster way has only two, but it also has several extra erroneous evaluations, which take a negligible amount of time.
What appears to be the case is that the integrand is evaluated at the right end point of the interval of integration.  In the "fast" way, that results in an illegal `NIntegrate` call, which evaluates quickly; in the "slow" way, it results in a valid `NIntegrate` call, which evaluates slowly.  It hardly seems like a robust way to speed up `NIntegrate`.

```
Trace[
 NIntegrate[a1, {x, 0, 2}],
 _NIntegrate,
 TraceInternal -> True, TraceForward -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Trace[
  NIntegrate[a2[x], {x, 0, 2}],
  _NIntegrate,
  TraceInternal -> True, TraceForward -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here are the timings of the components.  Note that `a1` and `a2[x]` take the same time to evaluate as the first integral below.  The extra integrals in the trace of `a2[x]`, show in the second integral below, take very little time.  Finally both integrals above end by evaluating the third integral below, which takes the same time as `a1` or `a2[x]`.

```
NIntegrate[x, {x, 0, 1}] // RepeatedTiming
(*  {0.0025, 0.5}  *)

Quiet@NIntegrate[2, {2, 0, 1}] // RepeatedTiming
(*  {4.2*10^-7, NIntegrate[2, {2, 0, 1}]}  *)

NIntegrate[0.5, {x, 0, 2}] // RepeatedTiming
(*  {0.0024, 1.}  *)
```